# From multiple queries into one query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My database "Films" contains columns: name, year (1980-2015) and rating of the film (1-10).
I would like to get the BEST FILM from EVERY year like:

```
The Beutiful Mind 2001 rating: 8.2
Catch Me If You Can 2002 rating: 8.0
```

I only can think how to do it in multiple queries like:

```
SELECT *
FROM movies
WHERE year = 2001
ORDER BY imdb_rating DESC
LIMIT 1;

SELECT *
FROM movies
WHERE year = 2002
ORDER BY imdb_rating DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

etc.

How can i achieve it in one query in SQL? What's the best way? Or maybe there is no problem with multiple queries in this case? Thanks for help :)

Comment: what happens if there are 2 films with a rating of 10 on the same year?

Comment: SQL Server does not have `limit` so I removed it as a tag.

Comment: Is this mysql or sqlserver? You tagged both.

Comment: Webeng - we can just choose one from the best; SQLChao, Gordon Linoff - i am just practising SQL queries, sorry for adding other tags :)

Answer (score 3):

One method is to use a subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select m.*
from movies m
where m.imdb_rating = (select max(m2.rating) from movies m2 where m2.year = m.year);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select name, year from (
select 
  name, year,
  row_number() over (partition by year order by rating desc) as rt
from movies ) RankTab
where rt = 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle sample**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/faa83/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, year, MAX(rating) FROM Films WHERE GROUP BY year
```

Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: SELECT name, year, MAX(rating) FROM Films
GROUP BY year; <--- quite simple and gives me expected results, thank You :)